# Only manual links with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, links

I want to use hyperref but only for links I create myself (with `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget`).

I know that hyperref automatically transforms other cross-references (created with `\label` and `\ref`) in hyperlinks as well, but I don’t want that. Is there a way to disable this « feature »?

Comment: Have you tried replacing all instances of `\ref` with `\ref*`?

Comment: But also, what's wrong with other cross-references being links?

Comment: I didn’t try \ref*, so I will try that. And there’s nothing wrong with other cross-references being links, but I don’t need that and I don’t want those links being visible on my documents

Comment: \ref* works fine. Thanks